# PHP redirect traffic using A/B testing based on 3 designs/probabilities

Tags: php, redirect, ab-testing

I am attempting to break down the logic of how to approach a coding assessment for a full stack job I applied for.

The specification states the following:

> Company X would like to A/B test a number of promotional designs to see which provides the best conversion rate. Write a snippet of PHP/Classic ASP/ASP.NET code that redirects end users to the different designs based on the database table below. Extend the database model as needed.

> i.e. - 50% of people will be shown Design A, 25% shown Design B and 25% shown Design C. The code needs to be scalable as a single promotion may have upwards of 3 designs to test.

> Please note that the percentage redirect should be shown as a percentage of all visits, to the site, not a percentage of the total number of users.

[image: Table entries]

I am trying to understand what the question means, specifically the percentage of all visits not users, what extra table entries are needed and how to do so efficiently.

I've no code to show for as I am having an issue understanding all of this.

Any help would be great,
Thank you.

Comment: I agree, I find that wording confusing, and I would word your answer (or comment in your code) what you think it means. I personally would say that a "user" probably means an "anonymous user" (not authenticated), so that is what we all think of as a human (or bot) using a "specific device", and "specific device" means something that a cookie can be bound to. Traditionally that be a single computer, but users can share their cookies across devices, so it could be multiple physical computers. When a user accesses a site, they are visiting it, and a visit usually has a duration called a session.

Comment: Sooo... maybe they are asking you to store the redirect choice in a session variable? I'd go further and show a couple of options possibly. Here's the session version which resets every _n_ minutes (probably 20) and here's the cookie version where you can control the duration of the A/B split for future visits.